# My Galaxy Tab 4 won't turn on?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I turned it on this morning and it was fine but it died. I tried turning it on later and the Galaxy Tab 4 logo popped up and it vibrated but the screen only turned on for maybe a second and then the screen went immediately black.

Comment: Did you put it in charge with a wall charger?

Answer (score 0):

Your cable to recharge is dead. Change your cable.